# Call google cloud function from google cloud tasks with oidc_token

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

**[UPDATE] I found where the problem was. I needed to create account for tasks service-[project-number]@gcp-sa-cloudtasks.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

I have problem to call Google Cloud Function from Google Cloud Task.
This problem appear only if I use oidc_token parameter.

I used Google Cloud Tasks tutorial from [here](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks).
I'm using same service account to create task and as `oidc_token` value.
I added owner role to that account.

Here is a code:

```
from google.cloud import tasks_v2
from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2

client = tasks_v2.CloudTasksClient()

project = '[Project]'
queue = 'fooqueue2'
location = 'asia-east2'
url = f'https://asia-east2-{project}.cloudfunctions.net/helloworld'
payload = None
in_seconds = 0

# Construct the fully qualified queue name.
parent = client.queue_path(project, location, queue)

# Construct the request body.
task = {
    'http_request': {
        'http_method': 'POST',
        'url': url,
        'oidc_token': {
            'service_account_email': f"{project}@appspot.gserviceaccount.com"
        }

    }
}


print(list(client.list_tasks(parent)))
response = client.create_task(parent, task)
print('Created task {}'.format(response.name))
```

then if fetch tasks I see

```
last_attempt {
  schedule_time {
    seconds: 1579860668
    nanos: 184117000
  }
  dispatch_time {
    seconds: 1579860668
    nanos: 185066000
  }
  response_time {
    seconds: 1579860668
    nanos: 206251000
  }
  response_status {
    code: 2
    message: "UNKNOWN(2): HTTP status code 0"
  }
}
```

Function available for all users.
I added owner, Cloud Functions Invoker, Service Account Token Creator, Cloud Tasks Service Agent roles  to this service_account_email.

Comment: 1) Edit your question with the environment that you are running this code on. 2) Double check that you have set up the correct permissions. https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-http-target-tasks#sa

Comment: 3) The account that is running this code must have Service Account User either at the project level or for the service account you are specifying. You are specifying a service account to be used and you need permission to do so.